# Firestore rules for a survey web app and a shared link

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to build a survey web app with firebase and have a certain user flow in my mind but I don't know if it can be done:

In this app you would signup/login and build your survey, which will be stored like this:

```
collection("creator").doc("creatorID").collection("surveyData").
```

After storing the data, you would get a link (e.g. webapp.com/forUser/secret/surveyName) you then can share with your friends. This link opens the same web app (from another entry point) but with anonymous authentication, hydrating and displaying only the content of this one survey from this one user.

There are two main problems here:

1. Pointing the user's web app to the right data via the link and only being able to access this one survey.
2. Writing the user answers in the creator's files

For 1) Can I pass a secret via the link (could I use the creatorID for this or is this not safe/secure?), which points the user to this one survey data (without granting any other access)? If so, how to do this without hard coding the secret into the authentication rules?

For 2) I could use a two-step process:
The user answers the survey questions and the results are stored in something like:

```
collection("user").doc("secret").collection("surveyData").
```

When the creator opens the app later on (or done via cloud functions), the app fetches all the answers from the shared secret doc. Can this be done in one step?

I hope this makes sense somehow. Maybe my ideas are way too complicated and there is an easy way to do this or are there some best practices in this regard?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right now, I don't believe there is a way to do what you're asking.  The team is looking into adding a hashing function to make this possible, without having to share personal information.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I built a `hashing` package into Firebase Rules. It might be possible to use that?

Example rules:

```
rules_version="2"

function hashUserCreds(auth) {
  let combinationOfCreds = string(auth.uid) /* + string(auth.other.stuff) */;
  // hashing.sha256 will work on strings as well, but it's more readable to
  // make this explicit.
  return hashing.sha256(combinationOfCreds.toUtf8()).toBase64();
}

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{ownerHash}/{surveyId} {
      function isOwner() {
        return hashUserCreds(request.auth) == ownerHash;
      }
      allow read;
      allow write: if isOwner();
      match /{responseId} {
        function isResponder() {
          return hashUserCreds(request.auth) == responseId;
        }
        allow update: if isResponder();
        allow read, create: if isOwner();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want open-responses then you change the final two permissions, but it sounds like you want the survey creator to choose who can respond which I've tried to express there.

Using hashes instead of names will provide better anonymity, obscure PII, and force the restriction that a user can only edit their data.